# How to save installed files in other drives?

Tags: software-installation, partitioning, ethereum

I am trying to install ethereum wallet in my system . But,My home folder does not have enough space for the entire block chain . I have my hard drive split into three partitions . My other partitions have enough space .How do I install the wallet in other partitions instead of the home partition ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use symlink in order to move away some folder. I don't know where your software stores its files in your home, but imagine that folder is named ethereum.

Move the ethereum folder (or move it with Nautilus)

```
mv ~/ethereum /media/%USER/<location where is mounted your partition>
```

Then create the symlink

```
mv /media/%USER/<location where is mounted your partition>/ethereum ~/ethereum
```

This will create a special file a bit like a shortcut in your home.

Comment: Are both the commands 'mv' ?